# To_Date Function Migration from oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am migrating my oracle database to SQL Server. What is the easiest way to convert `to_date` functions? I have many sql which use `to_date`.

For example I have an update query. It contains following line.What can be solution to convert it to SQL Server 2008 with minimum effort?

Sample Query Line

```
LAST_LOGIN=to_date('" & m_LAST_LOGIN & "','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) contains useful conversion information. From what you've given, the following should suffice. (Used with `getdate()` as an example date)

```
declare @LAST_LOGIN varchar(21)
set @LAST_LOGIN = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 104) + ' ' +convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 108)
```

There is nothing directly to convert it to the format you specify, so you have to concatenate the two conversions as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

```
LAST_LOGIN = convert(datetime, m_LAST_LOGIN, 20)
```

You can find further information from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: That will give a format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmmm, not what was requested. And the link to SQL 2000, not 2008. And in SQL, the variable woudl have been @LAST_LOGIN